# GCC 4.7.1 generalized constant expression issue with overload

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11, constexpr

I try to implement compile-time algorithm selection using template specialization.

I hash the following code:

```
template <class C>
    struct choose
    { 
        typedef size_t (*type)(const C*);
        static constexpr type value = java_string_hashcode<C>;
    };
```

I've specialized this structure for `char` type:

```
template <>
    struct choose<char>
    { 
        typedef size_t (*type)(const char*);
        static constexpr type value = fnv_1a_32_hash;
    };
```

But when I try to compile it, I get the following error with GCC 4.7.1:

> error: field initializer is not constant

I think the problem comes from the fact the `fnv_1a_32_hash` function is overloaded, even if IMO the implicit cast to `size_t (*)(const char*)` should deal with this problem.

I've finally found a workaround, by either renaming the overload OR simply casting the assignation:

```
static constexpr type value = (type)fnv_1a_32_hash;
```

**My question is**: is this a compiler bug? Or am I missing something? Please explain and cite specifications wherever needed.

---

fnv_1a_32_hash implementation details:

```
constexpr size_t fnv_1a_32_hash(const char* p, size_t h) noexcept
{ 
    return (*p == 0) ? h : fnv_1a_32_hash(p + 1, (h ^ *p) * fnv::prime);
} 

constexpr size_t fnv_1a_32_hash(const char* p) noexcept
{ 
    return fnv_1a_32_hash(p, fnv::offset_basis);
}
```

Comment: If at all, I'd think that the error message is a bug (not referring to overload being the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably already reported:

http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52366